# wxWidgets wxSpinCtrl incomplete type

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I'm confused in my header I specify a member `wxSpinCtrl * spinControl` and when I do like so in the constructor `spinControl = new wxSpinCtrl(this, wxID_ANY);` I receive a `error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class wxSpinCtrl’`. No other control I have used in wxWidgets so far has had this problem. Is there something special about this class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about it but you do need to `#include <wx/spinctrl.h>` before using it.

Comment: Is there a reason I need to do that for spin control but not frame or textctrl and a lot of other ones?

Comment: Something (either your own code or `<wx/wx.h>`) already includes `<wx/textctrl.h>`.

Comment: Right I thought wx/wx.h included everything though

Comment: No, it only includes the most commonly used headers.